# How do I change my taskbar position in dual monitors?

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, taskbar

A Linux noob here running lubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
I have my laptop connected to an external monitor on the left.
When I configured my setup, the panel(taskbar) would be there in the external monitor.
But when i set it as right of laptop LCD, it works fine.
Unfortunately, I can't change my desk setup in any way.
Is there any way to bring it to my laptop screen?

Comment: Don't you have an option in Setting > Display for "Main screen" ?

Comment: No. Not in lubuntu (to Garay)

Comment: right click on the panel, select "*Panel Settings*" which will open *Panel Preferences* where you can select which border of the screen you want the panel to appear, plus which monitor it appears on.  I'm not sure of your exact issue though sorry (is the external monitor connected only sometimes? or is this a constant issue?), and I often use `arandr` to automate a varying setup.. but I'm unsure of what your issue is sorry.